# at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull , the virtual phone crashes. How to solve this?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-glide

Here's my Question: I'm in the middle of a tutorial on how to create mobile applications and I'm encountering some real difficulties. Everything was working fine until I added the following line of code to allow me to access an online database:

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(Uri.parse(currentPlant.imageUrl)).into(holder.plantImage)
```

To try to solve the problem, I went to the Run and got the messages below. I was able to identify the error (java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null) but I don't know how to solve it. I absolutely need the help of others, I've been at it for hours

```
 2021-02-17 03:09:01.020 30727-30727/de.laurette.naturecollection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.laurette.naturecollection, PID: 30727
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:768)
        at de.laurette.naturecollection.adapter.PlantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PlantAdapter.kt:49)
        at de.laurette.naturecollection.adapter.PlantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PlantAdapter.kt:25)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
2021-02-17 03:09:01.021 30727-30727/de.laurette.naturecollection E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-02-17 03:09:01.164 30727-30727/de.laurette.naturecollection I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30727 SIG: 9
```

The PlantAdapter class contains the method or the line of code that generates the error:

```
    //cette classe sera donnee a notre recyclerview pour pouvoir adapter pour chaque plante son equivalent en image
class PlantAdapter(
    private val context : MainActivity,
    private val plantList : List<PlantModel> ,
    private val layoutId: Int
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PlantAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
            // elle permettra de porter la vue , une sorte de boite pour ranger touts les composants a controller
            class ViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
                val plantImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_item)
                //image de la plante
            }
    // nous permet dinjecter un composant
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent,false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // permettra de mettre a jour chaque modele avec la plante en question
    override fun onBindViewHolder( holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // recuperer les informations de la plante
        val currentPlant = plantList[position]

        // utiliser glide pour recuperer l'image á partir de son lien et venir laajouter a notre composant
        //GlideApp.with(context).load(Uri.parse(currentPlant.imageUrl)).into(holder.plantImage)
        GlideApp.with(context).load(Uri.parse(currentPlant.imageUrl)).into(holder.plantImage)

    }

    // permettra de renvoyer combien d'items on affichera dynamiquement
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = plantList.size
```

the next class represents the class where the image and its characteristics are added, including the imageUrl. The images had to be imported from the Pixabay online database. I have much more the impression that the link to the image doesn't work properly, I'm not sure.
Could you please tell me concretely what to do to solve my problem ? Unfortunately I don't have a solid base in Programming to solve this problem.  I am working on android and the phone crashes after being launched and sends back the message "keeps Stopping". I use Android studio and the gradle version is Gradle 4.1.2.

```
package de.laurette.naturecollection.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import de.laurette.naturecollection.MainActivity
import de.laurette.naturecollection.PlantModel
import de.laurette.naturecollection.R
import de.laurette.naturecollection.adapter.PlantAdapter
import de.laurette.naturecollection.adapter.PlantItemDecoration


class HomeFragment (
        private val context : MainActivity
        ) : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container , false )

        //creer une liste qui va stocker ces  plantes
        val plantList = arrayListOf<PlantModel>()

        // enregistrer une premiere plante dans notre liste (pissenlit)
        plantList.add(PlantModel(
            "pissenlit",
            "jaune soleil",
           "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/01/17/51/dandelion-335662_960_720.jpg",
            false
        ))

        // enregistrer une deuxieme plante dans notre liste (Rose)
        plantList.add(PlantModel(
         "Rose",
         "ca pique un peu",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/16/22/27/rose-3407234_960_720.jpg",
         false
    ))

        // enregistrer une troisieme plante dans notre liste (castus)
        plantList.add(PlantModel(
         "castus",
         "ca pique beaucoup",
         "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/06/20/47/prickly-pear-1501307_960_720.jpg",
         false
        ))

        // enregistrer une quatrieme plante dans notre liste (Tulipe)
        plantList.add(PlantModel(
            "Tulipe",
            "c'est beau'",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/13/21/19/tulip-2141216__340.jpg",
            false
        ))

        // recuperer le recyclerview
        val horizontalRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.horizontal_recycler_view)
        horizontalRecyclerView.adapter = PlantAdapter(context, plantList, R.layout.item_horizontal_plant)

        // recuperer le second recyclerview
        val verticalRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.vertical_recycler_view)
        verticalRecyclerView.adapter = PlantAdapter(context, plantList, R.layout.item_vertical_plant)
        verticalRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(PlantItemDecoration())

        return view

   }
}
```

GlideModule

```
import android.content.Context
import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.signature.ObjectKey

@GlideModule
class AppNameGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder)
        builder.apply { RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis().toShort()))}
    }
}
```

Comment: seems either `holder` or `holder.plantImage` is null

Comment: Thank you , but I still don't know how to solve my problem.